# Web Crawler - returning an array to be used in the next function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, request, cheerio

The first function I can confirm works correctly.

I'd like to return an array to the variable AtoZLinks so it can be used in the later function. I will make requests to each url in the array and extract more information from within those links.

Many thanks in advance, I've been working on this as a project for some days, I'm a beginner in jQuery, Web Crawling, JS, NodeJS and expressJS. Thrown myself in the deep end for work.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var router = express.Router();

    var fullUrl;
    fullUrl = [];

    var AtoZLinks = function(){
        var url = 'http://example1.com';
        request(url, function(error, response, html) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var fullUrl = [];
                var places = "Places";
                $('.clear a').each(function() {
                    var link = $(this);
                    link.each(function(index) {
                        var href = link.attr('href');
                        if (href.match(places)) {
                            // The urls from fullUrl here to be returned to parent variable.
                            fullUrl[index] = url + href; // Think something is wrong here... I've also tried "fullUrl.push(url + href);"
                            console.log(fullUrl); // This prints out all urls correctly

                        }
                    });
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < fullUrl.length; i++) {
                    console.log(fullUrl[i];
                } // This code only prints out the last url stored (So I'm thinking the urls are being stored incorrectly...)
            }
        });
    };

    /* GET crawler page. */
    router.get('/crawler', function(req, res, next) {
      AtoZLinks();
      next();
    }, function(req, res) {

    });

    module.exports = router;

    // Feel free to ignore the following work I've done or..
    // Your support with the the following function will be a bonus!
    // I need to use the links in the previous array variable in the following
    // function to extract further urls within those urls that I will work with.

    var url = AtoZLinks;

    request(AtoZLinks, function(error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            // This selector is the code needed to extract the links from within the
            // links in the AtoZLinks array.
            $('div.fclist-section.clear.list-four').each(function() {
                $(this).find('a').each(function() {
                    var link = $(this);
                    var href = link.attr('href');
                    fullUrl = url + href;
                    console.log(fullUrl);
                });
            });

        }
    );
```

Comment: Javascript is an asynchronous language meaning when you ask it to do something it will queue that process in a to-do list that executes in parallel in order to continue parsing the document. a way around this is to set up a callback chain that when the request is done it calls some function that you pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var arrURLs;

arrURLs = [
    'www.ask.com',
    'www.google.com',
    'www.bing.com',
    'www.yahoo.com'
];

AtoZLinks(arrURLs);

  var AtoZLinks = function(theURLs){
      for (var i = 0; i < theURLs.length; i++) {
          var url = theURLs[i];
          request(url, function(error, response, html) {
              if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                  var fullUrl = [];
                  var places = "Places";
                  $('.clear a').each(function() {
                      var link = $(this);
                      link.each(function(index) {
                          var href = link.attr('href');

                          //absolute match
                          if (href === url) {
                            //true
                          } else {
                            //false
                          }

                          //href contains url
                          if (href.indexOf(url) > -1) {
                            //true
                          } else {
                            //false
                          }                              

                          if (href.match(places)) {
                              // The urls from fullUrl here to be returned to parent variable.
                              fullUrl.push(url + href);
                              console.log(JSON.stringify(fullUrl));

                          }
                      });
                  });
              }
          });
      }
  };
```

Comment: I believe you've answered the bonus question: "How I can use the array of links in my next function". I will try to implement this now. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, I'm still struggling unfortunately. Firstly I need to first check to see if the correct values are being returned to the fullUrl array... Thanks.

Comment: I'm having issues proving to myself that the array contains the urls I stored... I hope this image is helpful... http://postimg.org/image/amr6e3nor/

Comment: Just got to work, unfortunately they block a ton of stuff, including postimg and jsfiddle, so I can't reach the link. Can you edit your question with the additional code? I made a small edit to my answer but not sure what your having problems with...

Comment: Ah okay I've added some comments... In the first function I essentially need to return links to the array called "fullUrl". The link will be the current url + href links.  I don't think it's working correctly.

Comment: You definitely need to use `push` to add the url to the array. `fullURL[index]` just operates on the array instance `index` refers to. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to peek inside the array, see edit...

Comment: Had to take my mind off this for a bit, moved onto extracting contact info. I used that push functionality as you've described and it worked.

Comment: I will have to mark this complete as you've answered the question and so kindly provided additional functionality that will come in useful! Much appreciated WhiteHat! Now to tackle some more challenges I've come across...